# OBIEE - Change pivot table row values based on prompt

Tags: pivot-table, prompt, obiee

I currently have a set of 12 pivot tables that I display based on a prompt. So the user simply clicks on a 'View By:' dropdown and chooses which table to view. This was accomplished through simple 'dummy tables' and a presentation variable.

My question: Can I set up a similar prompt to change the row values in my pivot tables?
For example, my row values are currently annual (12, 24, 36, ...). I would like to give the user the option to view the data on a quarterly (3, 6, 9, ...) and monthly (1, 2, 3, ...) basis.

Can I add a second 'View By:' dropdown so the user can select both the table, and row values the table is displayed on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making this much more difficult than it needed to be. The solution is to create **Groups** for the different buckets of values I was referencing ((1,2,3,...), (3,6,9,...), (12,24,36,...)). Then simply set the corresponding column filter to **Is Prompted** and add the newly created Groups as Choices to your **prompt's choice list**.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have a period dimension, with columns for year, quarter and month. If not, you may be able to use a variant of this.

If so, you can use the index col function. To set this up:

You would have a variable prompt, setting a presentation variable with the options [annual, quarterly, monthly]

In your answer, you would have one period column, changing the column formula to use the indexcol function. It would look something like:

```
INDEXCOL(CASE '@{myPresentationVariable}' WHEN 'annual' THEN 0 WHEN 'quarterly' THEN 1 WHEN 'monthly' THEN 2 END, period.year, period.quarter, period.month)
```

Comment: I actually have a 'development_age' column whose values are 1,2,3,...,12,15,18,...168. Incrementing by 1 for the first year then 3 after that. I'm trying to filter this column based on a presentation variable. Your answer thankfully got me 90% of the way there. I have this now: `CASE '@{time_period}' WHEN 'Year' THEN 12 WHEN 'Quarter' THEN 3 WHEN 'Month' THEN 1 END`. However what I want is something like this: `CASE '@{time_period}' WHEN 'Year' THEN (12,24,36,...,168) WHEN 'Quarter' THEN (3,6,9,...,48) WHEN 'Month' THEN (1,2,3,...,12) END`. This seems like basic SQL that I'm messing up.

Comment: @MattDionis In which case, can you filter your Analysis using a variation of the above, probably with an SQL filter?  
  
`0 = CASE '@{time_period}' WHEN 'Year' THEN MOD("development_age", 12) WHEN 'Quarter' THEN MOD("development_age", 3) WHEN 'Month' THEN 0 END`